# "global main" in Assembly

Tags: assembly, global, program-entry-point

I came across this snippet of code:

```
section .text
    global  main    ;must be declared for linker (gcc)
```

and then there is a function called main after this line:

```
main:    ;tell linker entry point
```

but i don't seem to understand what `global main` means, and the comment doesn't seem to help much...

i am using [this site](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/) as a reference to Assembly language programming.

i can analyse that `main` refers to the function main, but i don't understand the use of the `global` keyword...

thank you in advance...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`global main` basically means that the symbol should be visible to the linker because other object files will use it. Without it, the symbol `main` is considered local to the object file it's assembled to, and will not appear after the assembly file is assembled.

Comment: okay, so is the main just like a starting point in a program similar to C(++)'s int main()?

Comment: and is it that we use global just to make it visible to all the object files?

Comment: In this case, yes - but `global` can be used for any function.

Comment: (Basically summarizing ur answer to have better understanding)

Comment: okay, thankyou, i upvoted ur answer and will accept it as soon as stackoverflow allows me :)