# NASM not compiling with .global directive

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I have the following code in which I am trying to call an assembly function in C, which is trying to print "e" on the VGA Display (of QEmu):

```
void main()
{
 extern void put_in_mem();
 char c = 'e';
 put_in_mem(c, 0xA0);
}
```

The function put_in_mem is defined below:

```
.global _put_in_mem
_put_in_mem:
push bp
mov bp, sp
mov cx, [bp + 4]
mov ax, [bp + 6]
mov ax, 0xb800
mov ds, ax
mov [bx], cx
add bx, 0x1
mov cx, 0x7  
mov [bx], cx
pop bp
ret
```

When I compile the above assembly code using nasm I am getting the following error:

```
put_in_mem.asm:1: error: attempt to define a local label before any    non-local labels
put_in_mem.asm:1: error: parser: instruction expected
```

Why is this error coming?

Comment: `.global` aka `.globl` are GAS directives (https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Global.html), not NASM.  [What is global \_start in assembly language?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17898989)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> NASM gives special treatment to symbols beginning with a period. A label beginning with a single period is treated as a local label

NASM [does have a `global` directive](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc6.html), but it's written without an initial period. So perhaps you meant to write `global _put_in_mem`