# FASM gives me 'error: illegal instruction.' during assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, fasm

I just started coding in assembly. I have downloaded the [flat assembler](http://flatassembler.net/) and copied code from the internet. When I run this code, however, it says something like:

> ```
> section .text 
> error: illegal instruction.
> ```

My question is: what is wrong with this code?

```
section .text
   global_start     ;must be declared for linker (ld)

_start:             ;tells linker entry point
   mov  edx,len     ;message length
   mov  ecx,msg     ;message to write
   mov  ebx,1       ;file descriptor (stdout)
   mov  eax,4       ;system call number (sys_write)
   int  0x80        ;call kernel

   mov  eax,1       ;system call number (sys_exit)
   int  0x80        ;call kernel

section .data
msg db 'Hello, world!', 0xa  ;our dear string
len equ $ - msg              ;length of our dear string
```

Can somebody figure out what is going wrong?

Comment: `global_start`?  perhaps `global _start`, with a space, instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using *FASM*, but the code you got from the internet is for *NASM* . If you were to install [*NASM*](http://www.nasm.us/) into your Linux distro your code should work if you use *NASM* and you fix the bug at this line:

```
global_start     ;must be declared for linker (ld)
```

which should be:

```
global _start     ;must be declared for linker (ld)
```

The global directive needs a space before the label *_start*

If you wish to use *FASM* I recommend finding some examples and tutorial specific to that assembler. I would recommend *NASM* or GNU assembler (gas) if you are going to do any significant development in assembly.

Comment: Thank you, I downloaded  a NASM assmebler and it worked

Answer (score 3):

There is a space missing on the 2nd line

```
section .text
    global _start
```

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898989/what-is-global-start-in-assembly-language)

Answer (score 3):

write `section '.text'` with quote marks and there is no `global` afaik, use `public _start` instead. FASM could build executable ELFs for you with `format ELF64 executable` as the very first line. Now you can use `segment executable` and `entry _start` if you do not want to link it with other object-files.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using

```
section '.text'
```

For example,
You can use the code this way:

```
section '.text' code readable executable
```

OR

```
section '.idata'
```

Be careful to use '' when defining after section.